# Delete embeded message without removing text message discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've got a function in discord.py, !donate. That function has a link to my donation page, but an embeded is created with the title of the page and other info that I don't want. Is there any way to remove the embed without removing the text message?

```
@bot.command()
async def donate(ctx):
   await ctx.channel.send(ctx.author.mention + ", if you want to donate to the developer to contribute to the development of the bot, you can do so by visiting this link:\n\nhttps://donatebot.io/checkout/783063012163846194?buyer=777338793803513886\n\nAll donations are highly appreciated.")
```

Comment: put your link between < >, like `<https://donatebot.io/checkout/783063012163846194?buyer=777338793803513886>` and it won't create an embed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, add the link between `<` and `>`:

```py
@bot.command()
async def donate(ctx):
   await ctx.channel.send(ctx.author.mention + ", if you want to donate to the developer to contribute to the development of the bot, you can do so by visiting this link:\n\n<https://donatebot.io/checkout/783063012163846194?buyer=777338793803513886>\n\nAll donations are highly appreciated.")
```

Comment: Thanks! It was really helpful