# Removing an embed from a message in Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to figure out how to remove an embed from a message my Discord bot sends. As a joke, I made a bot to "censor" certain links, but so it's not mean, the bot reposts the link itself. Assuming any message from the bot has only one link in it, how do I either prevent the link embed from occurring, or have the bot delete the embed immediately?

Not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65136195/delete-embeded-message-without-removing-text-message-discord-py) because I do not know what the link will be, so I can't just find a certain substring and put angle brackets around it.

My code is as follows:

```
if any(substring in message.content.lower() for substring in ["www.example.com", "www.wikipedia.com"]):
    msg = await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is out of line!"
                                     f"\n> {message.content}\nThis misdeed has been noted, "
                                     "and future transgressions will result in severe penalties.")
    # remove embeds here?
    await message.delete()
```

(In addition, if there's a better way to do the `if` statement, let me know.)

Answer (score 5):

### Explanation

This can be accomplished by setting the `SUPPRESS_EMBEDS` flag to True, if your bot has `MANAGE_MESSAGE` permissions. In discord.py, this would be in the `Message.edit` method, where you set the `suppress` argument to `True`.

### Code

```py
if any(substring in message.content.lower() for substring in ["www.example.com", "www.wikipedia.com"]):
    msg = await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} is out of line!"
                                     f"\n> {message.content}\nThis misdeed has been noted, "
                                     "and future transgressions will result in severe penalties.")
    # remove embeds here!
    await message.edit(suppress=True)
```

### Reference

[Message Flags](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/channel#message-object-message-flags)

[discord.Message.edit](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.edit)