# How to remove a specific link preview (auto-embed) in a specific message with Discord.py bot?

Tags: python, api, discord, discord.py, bots

I have a problem with my python bot discord.py.
I need to remove the Twitter previews in some posts and I can't find a way to remove the link preview like in the discord client.

Right now I'm deleting the entire post and posting a new one writing who the original poster is followed by the link without its preview but it's messy.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague so I'm not quite sure if this is what you're asking about, but you can hide embedded previews by putting `<>` around a link.

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I was clear enough, my bad.  
I want to remove the embedded previews from an existing message (which triggers on_message())

Comment: Nobody (including bots) can edit the posts of other people, would open up a huge abusability and security risk. And I'm not aware of any other way of hiding the embedded previews outside of editing the message to use `<>`. You could in theory grab the content of every message and repost them with the brackets added in, but you can't edit them in-place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing an embed from a message in Discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951612/removing-an-embed-from-a-message-in-discord-py)

Comment: @iced Removing embeds isn't so much altering the content of any message, it is simply stopping the embed from being displayed. Any user or bot with "manage_message" permissions will be able to remove an embed from a message.

Comment: Ah yeah, good point, that would work too. Just got a little confused by the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [TheFungusAmongUs answer to an other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70951612/removing-an-embed-from-a-message-in-discord-py), we only need to use `message.edit(suppress=True)` on a message to suppress its visual embeddings:

```py
    @commands.command()
    async def some_command(self,ctx,*args):
        await ctx.message.edit(suppress=True)
```